# Javascript unit testing in Jasmin framework

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am new in JavaScript and unit testing. I have the following binary search code and I wanted to see if I can create some simple unit test cases for it in the Jasmine unit testing framework. However, for some reason my unit test is not working. 
<

```
script> 
let Searching = function (array, x, start, end) { 

    // Base Condition 
    if (start > end) return false; 

    // Find the middle index 
    let mid=Math.floor((start + end)/2); 

    // Compare mid with given key x 
    if (array[mid]===x) return true; 

    // If element at mid is greater than x, 
    // search in the left half of mid 
    if(array[mid] > x) 
        return Searching(array, x, start, mid-1); 
    else

        // If element at mid is smaller than x, 
        // search in the right half of mid 
        return Searching(array, x, mid+1, end); 
} 

// Driver code 
let array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]; 
let x = 5; 

if (Searching(array, x, 0, array.length-1)) 
    document.write("Element found!<br>"); 
else document.write("Element not found!<br>"); 

x = 6; 

if (Searching(array, x, 0, array.length-1)) 
    document.write("Element found!<br>"); 
else document.write("Element not found!<br>"); 
</script>                                    

//unit testing

Describe ('Search Binary Algorithm', function () {
    var search = new Searching();
  it('should search in binary', function(){
      console.log (search ());
       expect(search (x).toEqual(5));
   });

});
```

When I run this one syntax error unexpected identifier.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Element found` is not a valid syntax. Same goes for `Element not found`

Comment: @alfasin If fixed the Element found part and element not found. I have a issue writing a simple unit test for this code. I wrote the following but I am not sure if I am writing it.                                              //unit testing

Describe ('Search Binary Algorithm', function () {
    var search = new Searching();
  it('should search in binary', function(){
      console.log (search ());
       expect(search (x).toEqual(5));
   });

});

Comment: syntax errors are usually pretty informative. I'm not familiar with Jasmin but are you use it's `Describe` (with capital `D`) and not `describe`? also, where are the imports?

Comment: expect(search (x).toEqual(5)); are you sure x is defined in this scope? also, Searching seems to be taking 4 arguments but you did not prvide it any during your test execution. Also, I'm pretty sure the describe is case sensitive and you got the wrong case.

Comment: @VarunSharma and alfasin thank you for the comments. I fixed the unit test code. It was a few things wrong with it. x not being defined was one of them. I created the following simple test and it worked. describe ('Search Binary Algorithm', function () {
  let array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]; 
     let x = 13;
  
  
  it('should search in binary', function(){
 
  if (Searching(array, x, 0, array.length-1))
      console.log ('Value found');
     else
 console.log ('Value not found');
  
  
   });